# htaccess ReWrite with php Get-Strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I coded an online statistics page for my (minecraft) server, but I am having problems while trying to rewrite the url's to make it easier

I want to rewrite:

```
domain.com/players/player.php?p=QUERY
```

to:

```
domain.com/player/QUERY
```

I searched many pages, but many things didn't work. Right now I am stuck with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^player/(.*)$ players/player.php?p=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

If you could help me, that would be extremely great and very kind.

PS: the QUERY will be a String with the max length of 16 and containing numbers, letters and minusses, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /players/(player)\.php\?p=([a-z0-9-]{1,16}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^player/([a-z0-9-]{1,16})$ /players/player.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```